# Is there a way to disable redirect and send http status as 302 in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, http-redirect, http-status-code-302

Am trying to find a way to disable redirect in spring boot and send http status code as 302. Is there a way it is possible. Please let me know if it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

after proper testing and debugging, I found out the redirect is not happening in Spring boot but in the SoapUi. Not sure how to remove redirect in soapUi, so using postman where we have options in the settings section, and configuration is "automatically follow redirects" to off. So this proves spring boot won't redirect with http-header having 302 as value in the response.